# How to call a .exe file from Java with some parameters

Tags: java

I need to call cowsay.exe (this program uses symbols for 
drawing animals) and executes the command: cowsay "hello". How do I pass "hello" as a parameter?

```
public class cowsay {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\cowsay.exe","cowsay Hello").start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code above is executing the command D:\cowsay.exe "cowsay hello".

Answer (score 3):

You use the java.lang.Runtime class:

```
public class cowsay {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process process = 
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cowsay hello");
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Fungucide pointed out, your could use the RunTime class. However I suggest that you use the method which accepts the parameters as an array.
Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
  Try{
     String[] command={"D:\\cowsay.exe","cowsay","Hello"};
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
}
```

This is if you want "cowsay" as an parameter. If you d=only want "hello" as a parameter then do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
  Try{
     String[] command={"D:\\cowsay.exe","Hello"};
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
}
```